# Migrate deprecated Facebook App

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

I have inherited a Facebook App that is using the now deprecated REST API and fb_sig, and uses ColdFusion. The App seems to now load the home page, but none of the interior pages or functions appear to be working - so I've put it in Sandbox mode. I'm having a hard time determining the path to take to migrate this app to work with current Facebook API. Any suggestions, or is it better to start over from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it all depends on how much code is not using deprecated API's and how much code can still be used and how comfortable you are with that code.

Where to start? You'd have to replace all the Facebook API calls that aren't supported anymore.

Comment: So if, for example, I have this line of depreciated code: <fb:tab-item href="#request.canvasUrl#" title="Browse" <cfif attributes.tab eq "browse">selected="true"</cfif>/> is there an online resource that instructs how to replace that with newer supported code?

Comment: I think you'll have to figure out for each FBML tag what it used to do and then rewrite that in HTML and the new FB API. btw, it's called "deprecated" not "depreciated".